# How to logout user with React Native WebView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a problem that I can't solve.
My React Native WebView is located in a certain screen. The URL used in that WebView works with a SSO that logs the user with a token and send them to a certain page. The problem is that the user keeps logged in the web app. So I set the incognito prop to true and in iOS worked as expected but in Android failed. And then I setted the domStorageEnabled false but in Android I got a blank screen, in iOS it worked perfectly because according to the props it only affects Android.

```
const TestComponent = () => {

  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUrlSSOToken() {
        const token = await getCache('@token');
        let url = `https://test.com/sso/expected_page/${token}`;
        setUrl(url);
    }
    getUrlSSOToken();
  }, []);


  return (
    <WebView incognito={true}  thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={false} domStorageEnabled={false} source={{uri: url}}/>
  );
}
```

I should add that the web app is coded in a way that when the user is logged and goes to the **[https://test.com/sso/expected_page/${token}](https://test.com/sso/expected_page/$%7Btoken%7D)** URL it redirects them to a page that I don't want to show. How can I make something that works in Android as well as it works in iOS? Maybe hit a logout page somewhere?